# How to access Router or (Store/Fetch) Data in an application delegate on Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I have to write an application delegate to setup call listeners for Twilio. Unfortunately, for some unknown reason, whenever I change views or call modal views, the callListeners stop working even when I declared them in the main app.component file.

So I'm thinking of just using app delegate to store the call data, tricky part is i need access to authentication service provider to check if the user has an active token

Answer (score 0):

Application delegate runs outside Angular context, you may not able to get access to any Angular dependencies in there.

May be you could fire an event from delegate on application module, listen to the event form any Angular component where you would have access to any Angular dependencies.